# Storyboard won't make button action

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, drag-and-drop, storyboard

For some reason I can't drag and drop from my storyboard button into my View Controller class.
All of the classes are named correctly, and I've tried logging out of my computer, shutting it down, and killing the XCode process. Nothing seems to work. Can anyone who's faced this kind of thing before give me any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in your case is that you have not set the UIViewController Class in Identity Inspecter . Please refer to the screenshots

Screenhot1:
[image]

Screenshot2:
[image]

In the first screenshot I am setting the Class of the UIViewController as the name of the Class of my View Controller (in my case the name is 'viewController').

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Delete and recreate your View Controller class. That how I fixed it (only got this problem 1 time).

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you cannot drag and drop from any new added view controller into the corresponding .h ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your situation, you can do one thing. Just tag your button in xib to identify that specific button. In ViewDidload , you can retrieve your button by below code..

```
#define YOURBTNTAG 44

for (UIView *subBtn in self.view.subviews)
{
  if ([subBtn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
  {
   if ( subBtn.tag == YOURBTNTAG)
    {
        self.btn = subBtn;
        break;
    }
  }
}
[self.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(test:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Note :** 1) If your class is correctly defined in Xib, It'll work otherwise cann't.

2) If self.view is nil, You have to delete your xib and create new one to do your work. Because It may have naming(class name or xib name) mistake or other mistake.